# Where is “Jenkins URL” configuration stored?

Tags: jenkins, puppet

I'm trying to set up a non-default URL as part of a puppet script that installs Jenkins. I know how to edit the value via the web UI but I can't seem to find where the value is actually stored. I've looked through the jenkins_home folder and apache and have yet to find it.

Comment: The correct place to change this is <yourjenkins>/configure. Look for "Jenkins URL". http://stackoverflow.com/a/9089610/3253937

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It stores it in a rather unlikely place: `hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml` in Jenkins home folder.

Comment: In case someone runs into this nowadays, it's `jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml` in recent versions

Comment: do you guys know if changing the URL in that file should actually change the URL for Jenkins? Or must it be changed from the management console?

Answer (score 19):

I'm on Jenkins 2.68 and it's stored at `jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml` under the Jenkins home folder.

Comment: do you know if changing the URL in that file should actually change the URL for Jenkins? Or must it be changed from the management console?

Answer (score 11):

If you don't find the URL when grepping Jenkins home, it's because you didn't saved the configuration. If not set, Jenkins fallback to request URL, without saving it on disk.

```
root@jenkins-dev:/var/lib/jenkins# grep jenkinsUrl *.xml
jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml:  <jenkinsUrl>http://jenkins-dev.lxc/</jenkinsUrl>
root@jenkins-dev:/var/lib/jenkins#
```

Comment: Jenkins home directory in mac (installed with homebrew) is ~/.jenkins

Answer (score 0):

The url can be found in the UI/web app under configuration > Jenkins Location; alternatively, login to your server and cat the contents at this location:
var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml

Answer (score -3):

The file config.xml in the Jenkins home folder.

Comment: Right. I'm aware of that file but as far as I can tell the URL value isn't stored in it.

Answer (score -3):

I did a grep for "http" in my Jenkins root directory led me to hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml

I'm using Jenkins version 1.462