# Migrated Jenkins keeps redirecting to original domain

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, migration

I migrated Jenkins with `thinBackup` plugins. When I restart my new Jenkins master, accessing it via http://new_jenkins_ip:8080 will redirect me to https://old_jenkins_domain.

My old Jenkins runs with services, it was setup long ago. My new Jenkins runs in k8s, I edited stable/jenkins chart and deployed it with Helm.

At first, I thought Jenkins URL is the cause, so I change configuration in `jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml` (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723735/where-is-jenkins-url-configuration-stored/36031036)) and restart Jenkins by killing its pod (I deploy new Jenkins in k8s). But it's still redirecting to https://old_jenkins_domain.

I also try copying entire JENKINS_HOME ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another)) directory and yes, it's still redirecting to https://old_jenkins_domain.

Another problem is that I'm using `github-oauth` and `matrix-auth` plugins and if I don't install these before performing thinBackup migration, Jenkins will fail to start up and restart itself forever. I want to know why.

I actually can access http://new_jenkins_ip:8080/login but when I hit login, `github-oauth` just throw an NullPointerException.
I might try this [python](https://github.com/prasadsalvi21/JenkinsMigration) to migrate plugins because I think `thinBackup` can't migrate all the `github-oauth` config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `github-oauth` plugins that keep directing me to my old site. I new oauth app in github and let it redirecting to my new IP.

Comment: Sir ,you saved me from hours of headache, two times in a year...