# How to Set the context path in Windows by modifying the hudson.xml configuration file

Tags: php, apache, jenkins

There are so many question with this topics I could not found a proper answer,

I referred this link : http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Running+Hudson+behind+Apache

So I want to run my jenkins behind apache, How can i do that ?

Comment: The link you have seems to be a complete solution.. what have you tried so far that is not working?  have you followed their solution to the letter?

Comment: @sircapsalot Yes... except this "Set the context path in Windows by modifying the hudson.xml configuration file" Dont know how to do that

Comment: have you seen - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089566/jenkins-website-root-path

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Toby Jackson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089566/jenkins-website-root-path#answer-9119377)

> You need to specify the context/prefix of the Jenkins instance, this
>   can be done by modifying the Jenkins configuration as follows; Either,
>   set the context path by modifying the jenkins.xml configuration file
>   and adding --prefix=/jenkins (or similar) to the entry. Or Set the
>   context path when using by adding --prefix=/jenkins to JENKINS_ARGS in
>   /etc/default/jenkins (Ubuntu) or in an appropriate startup file.
>
> So, how to find these things...
>
> The Jenkins.xml file should be in the $JENKINS_HOME directory, I'm not
>   sure if Mac OS has the "updatedb" and "locate " commands, but you
>   could try doing updatedb && locate jenkins.xml
>
> Also, have a look in the startup scripts; /etc/init.d if installed
>   from a package, or add the JENKINS_ARGS to the environment properties
>   for the User running Jenkins (append to ~user/.profile) or the
>   arguments for the container running Jenkins.

You might have been confused when this said "hudson.xml" - Hudson is Jenkins' former name, and you appear to be using outdated documentation.  The last time this was updated was Jan 27, 2011.

use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+apache instead.