# Change jenkins container deployment root path

Tags: jenkins

I have pulled jenkins docker container to install on docker. It is working fine from functional perspectives. However, the URL to access jenkins is `http://<host>:8080/`. I want this URL to be changed to `http://<host>:8080/jenkins`.

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -u 0 -v /opt/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`

I did look at [Jenkins website root path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089566/jenkins-website-root-path) post but it did not help me to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using docker stack but it would be the same with docker-compose (same syntax)
You pass the CLI arguments --prefix=/ci/dashboard in the JENKINS_OPT variable

Here is my jenkins.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkinsci/jenkins
    ports:
     - 1080:8080
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```

I deploy with

```
$ docker stack deploy -c jenkins.yml jenkins
```

source:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/68

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to run jenkins in docker
   AND
2. If you are coming from the official Jenkins docu here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/
3. You can add `--env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"` to the provided `docker run` command like:

```
docker run \
  --name jenkins-blueocean \
  --rm \
  --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client \
  --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" \
  --publish 8086:8080 \
  --publish 50000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  myjenkins-blueocean:2.332.2-1
```

4. If you are using apache2 you should leave there an entry like

```
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Proxy http://localhost:8086/jenkins*>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8086/jenkins nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8086/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://your.host.com/jenkins


<Location /jenkins/>
  ProxyPassReverse /
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Location>

Header edit Location ^http://your.host.com/jenkins/ https://your.host.com/jenkins/
```

Just like described here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-apache/

and here, e.g. for nginx or others:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-with-jenkins/