# How can i change the contextpath of jenkins?

Tags: apache, jenkins

We have a situation trying to run jenkins behind apache,

we need to specify a new context path because we already have an instance of jenkins in ./Jenkins, so we try to use the parameter --prefix=/jenkins2/ in order to have the 2 instances separated.

The problem is that with that parameter, when i hit the url http://myserver.com/jenkins2 i have this:

**HTTP ERROR 404**

Problem accessing /. Reason:
    Not Found

Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT

any help?

Comment: Running Jenkins in docker? Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72000796/1485527

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/sysconfig/jenkins or /etc/default/jenkins change the follow line

```
JENKINS_ARGS=""
```

to

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--prefix=/jenkins2"
```

you can also run in a different por changing JENKINS_PORT in the same file.

Probably yours is not working because the "/" in the end "/jenkins2/"

If you can't find these files, you can check where is viewing the content of /etc/init.d/jenkins, in the line starting with "JENKINS_CONFIG="

If you are not running jenkins as service you can run:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --prefix=/jenkins2
```

Comment: Whats is your OS?

Comment: its a OpenSuse server

Comment: Edit the file /etc/sysconfig/jenkins. I update my answer.

Comment: java -jar jenkins.war --prefix=/jenkins2 this cause the http error that i mentioned in the answer.

The problem is that i have an older version of jenkins running in a tomcat, an a new version running with the embebed jenkins server.

The older version aim to http://jenkins.mycompany.com/jenkins/ 

Im triying to aim the new version in order to acced from http://jenkins.mycompany.com/jenkins2/

Comment: Try jenkins.mycompany.com:8080/jenkins2