# How to place Jenkins behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, jenkins, devops

The Nginx server is running HTTPS linked to the domain `www.example.com`.
The Jenkins is running on the same server on a port 8080.
I have successfully configured Nginx to route all unsecured traffic from port 80 to the secured one via port 443 using Nginx config `location` statement:

```
location /  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Now, typing `www.example.com` into the web browser connects me to Jenkins web interface over the secured HTTPS. That's is great. But the problem is that with the `location /`  all the traffic to `www.example.com` is routed to Jenkins.

I would like to go ahead and modify the `location` to contain `/jenkins`:

```
location /jenkins  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Trying to load Jenkins from `www.example.com/jenkins` brings up an error:

[image]

To fix it, I use Nginx `rewrite` statement:

```
location /jenkins  {
    rewrite ^/jenkins?$ / break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Now, I am able to access Jenkins at `www.example.com/jenkins`, but only at Jenkins root URL `/`.
Clicking any navigation link in Jenkins web interface, brings up `404 Not Found` error.

Again, the `https://www.example.com/` connects me to Jenkins root `/` and loads the main Jenkins web interface. Clicking `Manage Jenkins` button in the Jenkins web interface attempts to route to `https://www.example.com/manage`. It breaks with the same `404 Not Found` error.

I've tried to use another rewrite regex that removes the word `/jenkins` in the URL before sending the request to `http://localhost:8080`:

```
location /jenkins  {
    rewrite ^/jenkins(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

The navigation to the main root Jenkins site now have to be done with

`www.example.com/jenkins/`

(the URL must end with the forward slash `/`).

It does load the main Jenkins interface. But again, all the Jenkins internal navigation links are broken.

After playing around, I have noticed, that clicking `Manage Jenkins` button routes to

`https://www.example.app/manage`

resulting to `404 Not Found` error.

If I would modify this URL to

`https://www.example.app/jenkins/manage`

it successfully loads the `Manage Jenkins` page. It seems the solution is somewhere nearby...

Is there a way to configure Jenkins routing so it inserts a custom `/jenkins` in to the internal URLs it creates, so clicking the `Manage Jenkins` button would result to

`https://www.example.app/jenkins/manage`

instead of

`https://www.example.app/manage` ?

How to make it work?

## Jenkins Internal URLs:

```
https://www.example.com 
https://www.example.com/view/all/newJob
https://www.example.com/projectRelationship
https://www.example.com/fingerprintCheck
https://www.example.com/manage
https://www.example.com/me/my-views/view/all/
https://www.example.com/lockable-resources/
https://www.example.com/job/freestyle/18/console
```

Comment: Jenkins has configuration settings to manifest itself under desired location path - research and use that one - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089566/jenkins-website-root-path/22833707

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting the incoming URLs with `rewrite` statement inside of the body of `location` function I have implemented the subdomains to separate the traffic to the web page from the traffic to Jenkins.

First, I have registered the subdomain name with my DNS registrator (Google Cloud DNS service in my case).
As a result, I have now the following Record Sets:

```
DNS NAME                    Type      Data 
example.com.                A        345.678.90.1 (server public IP)
www.example.com.            CNAME     example.com.  

jenkins.example.com.        A        345.678.90.1 (same server public IP)
www.jenkins.example.com.    CNAME    jenkins.example.com.
```

Next, I've generated the certificates using `certbot` with:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d jenkins.example.com -d www.jenkins.example.com
```

Lastly, I've edited Nginx config file located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` by adding two `server` declaration each with its own `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` (one for `example.com` and another for `jenkins.example.com`

Since both servers are acting separately from each other listening two different URLs (`example.com` and `jenkins.example.com`) both have a `location` configured at the root `\`.

For the `example.com` web site it is:

```
location /  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
}
```

For the `jenkins.example.com` it is

```
location /  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Now, to get the web site, I use `www.example.com`
To get the Jenkins Web UI, I use `www.jenkins.example.com`

Please feel free to post another solution or improve this one as well as indicate the possible issues using the solution like the one I posted.