# How to customize the URL for Jenkins docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed jenkins docker in my system and am able to access the jenkins console with the local host url like http://localhost:8080.

Now, I wanted to share the URL with group of people. Some one suggest the steps to configure.

Comment: Hello. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089566/jenkins-website-root-path It could be a duplicated question. I would suggest anyway to use a proxy like https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of your Jenkins config as you haven't shared an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So, this is how you launch a new Jenkins service that can be accessed by others on the network through Nginx.

We will be using [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) to facilitate the process. We're using the official [Nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) and [Jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins) images from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

- Create a folder that contains the needed config files :

```sh
mkdir ~/jenkins-docker
cd ~/jenkins-docker
touch docker-compose.yml
touch nginx.conf
```

- Make a home directory for Jenkins :

```sh
mkdir ~/jenkins
```

- Create Jenkins and Nginx docker-compose services (docker-compose.yml file content):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins
    container_name: jenkins
    privileged: true
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - jenkinsnet

  server:
    image: nginx:1.17.2
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf # your nginx config file
      - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx # log files
    restart: always
    command: nginx-debug -g 'daemon off;'
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - jenkinsnet
    depends_on: 
      - jenkins

networks:
  jenkinsnet:
```

- Create an Nginx config to make Jenkins accessible on the network (nginx.conf file content)

```
events {}

http {
    include mime.types;

    ## logging
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] [$server_name] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # server config
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

- Run your services :

```sh
cd ~/jenkins-docker
docker-compose up
```

- Access Jenkins on your local machine on `http://localhost:8080`
- Access Jenkins from other devices on your network on `http://local-ip-address:8000` (ex: `http://192.168.1.23:8000`)
- Access Jenkins from other devices connected to the internet `http://public-ip-address:8000` (ex: `http://56.137.222.112:8000`) (Port Forwarding required if you're setting up on your home network. If you're using cloud providers, allow access to port `8000` for your instance)

#### Further Explanation

We are launching two docker containers. The `jenkins` container contains a Jenkins installation, accessible on port `8080` in the container. Consequently, we published that port in the `jenkins` service config, so that we can access it from the host machine using :

```yaml
ports:
  8080:8080
```

The `nginx` container contains a reverse proxy server that allows you to make the Jenkins server accessible by routing all incoming traffic on a certain port to it.

In order for the `nginx` service to route traffic to the `jenkins` service, we create and assign a single network to the services:

```yaml
# network creation :
networks:
  jenkinsnet:

# network assignement :
networks:
  - jenkinsnet
```

When the two containers belong to the same network, We are able to use the container names as hostnames. So accessing `localhost:1234` on the `jenkins` container can be done from the `nginx` container using `jenkins:1234`. So, in the `nginx.conf` file we route all traffic coming to Nginx to the Jenkins server using :

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080;
}
```

Nginx is listening on port `80` :

```
server {
    listen 80;
...etc
```

So we publish the port to the host machine so that Nginx can pick up the incoming requests :

```yaml
ports:
  - 8000:80
```

I chose port `8000` but you can use any port you like.